# How to go next line when the it is in the middle of a sentence in a div tag?

Tags: html, css

In my project I want to make a contract with html that admin can print in pdf format. Everything in the html output is ok but the pdf is disordered. Imagine it is a long sentence and I want some part of it goes to the next line.
Actually the width of sentence is not determined because some of the contract gets values from server and the width is not Specified size. So I don't know in which part of sentence it goes to the next line. and also I should say the fields that  get value from server and the other part of the contract that is just simple text should be next to each other and I did it with ***display: inline-block***. I think the problem is this.

How can I do it with css in a div tag?

Comment: You can use <br> to insert a new line.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `<br>` tag which stands for break :)

Comment: Actually the width of sentence is not determined because some of the contract gets values from server and the width is not Specified size. So I don't know in which part of sentence it goes to the next line.

Comment: Ahhh i see, you will want to do something along the lines of restricting the width of the div which contains the text, this should automatically wrap the text to the next line when it reaches this width